# Custom pop up dialog with imageview dragable android

Tags: android, popup, draggable

I've followed this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.co.id/2014/01/implement-drag-and-drop-movable.html with some modification. I want to show image on it and make the pop up draggable.

now it's work. but the problem is the image can not move to the corner of the screen. can anyone give me a solution about this issue? any suggestion would be appreciated

this my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dismiss"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="close"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this my activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
    btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                    (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imgResult);
            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/toy", null, getPackageName());

            Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(res);

            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }});

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

            popupView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                int orgX, orgY;
                int offsetX, offsetY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        orgX = (int) event.getX();
                        orgY = (int) event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        offsetX = (int)event.getRawX() - orgX;
                        offsetY = (int)event.getRawY() - orgY;
                        popupWindow.update(offsetX, offsetY, -1, -1, true);
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }});
        }

    });
}

}
```

Comment: According to details provided, the problem of the image is not moving to the corner of the screens might be because of the "offsetX, offsetY" you are getting in "onTouch" listener. You have to monitor the screen height and width and cross check with "offsetX, offsetY" that you are getting in "OnTouch". additionally some android devices [like Motorola, Samsung] consider status bar's height and Navigation bar's height as well, so you have to consider that too.

Comment: can u give me more detail ? sample code maybe. because i am newbie. i just follow tutorial. thanks before

Comment: Code posted by you worked fine when I tested on device[Samsung device], Image was moving on screen [each and every corner]. Please let me know what exactly you want to achieve and what is going wrong at your end.

Comment: yes if the picture is in original size it's work fine. it can moving to the corner. but when u force drag it, the image was resize right ? become smaller, in this condition, the picture cannot move to the corner

Comment: and also if the image widht and height too big, buttom dismiss was hide